# How to disable dragging feature in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to stop the `dragging` feature inside a `draggable` method.

```
$('#dragitem').draggable({
            scroll : false,
            drag: function(event, ui){
                 //a if statement
                 if(….){
                    //I want to stop the dragging here.                       
                 }
            }
 });
```

Is there a way to stop the `dragging` inside the drag function? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `return false;`? Try adding it to that block. That should end the function.

Comment: @Luxelin no it doesn't work.

Comment: did you get it working yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#dragitem").draggable({ disabled: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#dragitem').draggable({
      scroll : false,
      drag: function(event, ui){
           //a if statement
           if(….){
                //I want to stop the dragging here.
                event.preventDefault();                      
           }
      }
 });
```

Comment: and if that doesn't work, try `e.stopPropogation();`

Comment: I think you mean `event.stopPropogation();`? There's no `e` defined in your code as far as I can tell.

Comment: Why we need `event.stopPropogation()` ? There're no event from the parent node in here. Just `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

I've been in this situation before and I've triggered `mouseup` event here for lack of a better solution:

```
drag: function(event, ui){
    if(true) {
        // stop dragging
        $(document).trigger('mouseup');                  
    }
}
```